# Community builder login Api?

Tags: joomla, joomla-community-builder

I have the following situation. I'm building a completely new joomla site and community from scratch. The client wants to use community builder for user management, mainly because kunena and in the future jomsocial will be added. Logically, I want al those parts to be connected, and to be maintainable in an easy way.

I wan't to create a class that handles the login information from my own form, preferable using ajax. Unfortunately, I can't find the slightest heads up on how to do that, while it seems to me that, that shouldn't be to hard, right?

Hope someone knows the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Had a little look on Google and found this Login module that supports Community Builder and uses Ajax technologies:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication/20452

This module is however commercial. I give feedback on this, but I have never used it before. However, I think the ratings and reviews speak for themselves.

I'm not sure why you want to use your own form for the login module as Community Builder allows you to add your own field and so on.

Hope this helps